# Special characters in QGIS script tools

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to write a script that includes a selection from the attribute table.
But my data is in Hungarian, so it includes special characters like: öüőűáéí

So when there is non of these in the query it executes, otherwise I get this:

Is there a setting or something to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the layer's encoding to `ISO 8859-2`? You can change this by right-clicking your layer and going to `Properties > General > Layer info > Data source encoding`. The attribute table should show the characters correctly. Then test to see if your query works =)

Comment: No it did not work :(

Comment: Tell us what encoding you are using in this table and yours computer default encoding.
It would be easier if you use UTF-8 everywhere, rather than local encodings like ISO-8859-2.

Comment: Have a look at [How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: I'd like to solve this but within modeler. Is It possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you use diacritic characters?

It might be a simple python problem. Open the python editor in QGIS, and ensure that you start with the two comment lines on the top, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('utilizador') 
layer = layers[0]
it = layer.getFeatures()

layer.startEditing()
for feat in it:
  layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), 7, u'Jó napot kívánok!')

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-2 -*-

name = "Algyő"
print name

I did this in the console, but the result is still AlgyÅ

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is also good for Hungarian characters. The ISO-8859-2 is much older. You must know which of these two you are using.

Comment: Well, as my ESRI shape is in utf-8 I started with that, than I give the ISO-8859-2 a try, but also did not help. But anyways, what really bothers me is that if I run that little code (also with utf-8) in any consoles it works but not here in qgis.

Comment: Did you try to prefix the strings with a `u`? `u'Jó napot kívánok!'`

Comment: with the prefix it works in the console thank you! However I still have to find out how to use this in processing algorithm