# QGIS Processing algorithm cannot deal with special characters in input

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, encoding, qgis-2.18

My aim is to write an algorithm, where the user selects a settlement name, and numeric value, from which a query is generated, and a selection proceeds on the selected layer, than the selection result is exported to a new shape. It works, but when the input settlement name includes a special character, it fails.

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##[Example scripts]=group
##lyr=vector
##nev=string Szeged
##depth=number 3000

from qgis.core import *
import processing

input = processing.getObject(lyr)

print depth
print name
l = input
expr = QgsExpression(" \"MELYSEG\">'{}' AND \"TLP\"LIKE'{}'".format(depth, nev))
it = input.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
input.setSelectedFeatures( ids )

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(input, "D:/Data/output.shp", "utf-8", input.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", 1)
```

The field type of "MELYSEG" is a float the "TLP" is a string.

When I have an input like this (note the ő character in the name):
[image]

I get the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0151' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I always do to handle unicode in expressions is to prepend a `u` to the expression string, in this way:

```
expr = QgsExpression( u"\"MELYSEG\" > {} AND \"TLP\" LIKE '{}'".format( depth, nev ) )
```

Also note, as `MELYSEG` field is of type `float`, you don't need the single quotes for its value.

I suggest you to test your expressions directly in the QGIS GUI first, and only when you have an expression that works, implement it in PyQGIS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the [encode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) function for your string input.

So try replacing:

```
expr = QgsExpression(" \"MELYSEG\">'{}' AND \"TLP\"LIKE'{}'".format(depth, nev))
```

with this:

```
expr = QgsExpression(" \"MELYSEG\">'{}' AND \"TLP\"LIKE'{}'".format(depth, nev.encode(u'ISO-8859-2')))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `encode()` function in python:

```
expr = QgsExpression(" \"MELYSEG\">'{}' AND \"TLP\"LIKE'{}'".format(depth, nev).encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: 6 second difference ;)

Comment: :) but it seems yours is correct, I have added ascii but i think it should be utf as ascii is the one who failed to encode as per error message in the question. right ?

Comment: I based the encoding on the OP's [previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219643/special-characters-in-qgis-script-tools) so yours could be correct, just depends what the OP is looking for in the new question =)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I might be dummy, but altought there is no error message now, the script runs but without results. Sorry for the so many questions I am pretty new to pyqgis.